# MariadB Europe/Athens Timezone

Tags: mariadb, timezone

I am using Debian 8, mariadb 10.4, nginx 10.3, php7.3-fpm.
My timezone configuration was like this:

1. Debian: Europe/Athens ( through tzselect command )
2. PHP: Europe/Athens , Default timezone UTC
3. Mariadb: Europe/Athens

**The problem:**

My records where inserted on DATETIME fields with UTC timezone ( 3 hours earlier).

I guess it the default timezone on php that makes the problem, but I don 't know how to solve it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I think nothing is wrong. The records are inserted in the database in utc time, but my application is configured for my time zone. So when using the dates from the db it haw the informatoin for timezone and shows the correct hour.

Answer (score 0):

`DATETIME` is like taking a picture of your local clock.

Check these:

```
SHOW VARIABLES LIKE '%zone%';

SELECT NOW();
```

If `NOW()` does not show Athens time, then something is set incorrectly.

Comment: It is Athens time but I chanded my post because I was wrong thinking I solved the problem. See my update question. Thanks for your answer